# IIS 7: Redirect all request to Default.aspx

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

We want to redirect all request in an ASP.NET site to ~/Default.aspx to close the site.  We are using IIS7.  The site has paths like this that return a page:

http://test.com/operating

We are using url rewriting.  We want requests similar to those to be redirected to ~/Default.aspx

http://test.com/*/
http://test.com/*.aspx
http://test.com/*/*.aspx

We would normaly use something like this in web.config:

```
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Default.aspx">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="Default.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
```

The problem with this is that it won't redirect folder url like this

http://test.com/*/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [HttpRedirect](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpRedirect)?
You'll have to install the feature first though.

Comment: Yep it helped thanks!  But you can't make a redirect to the same domain or it'll do an infinite redirect.  But other than that it worked!  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can place a file named `App_Offline.htm` in the root of any ASP.NET application.  This results in taking ANY .NET page request and outputting the contents of the htm file instead of the requested page.  It isn't actually a redirect, but it is a very simple way to take an entire site down.  If you need to, you can also use a standard meta refresh to send any requested to a new location (just remember not to do so to an ASPX file in the same site).

Answer (score 0):

You could do this if no files exist anymore.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/Default.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write something like this in Global.asax (mind you, it's just an example, not production-ready code):

```
Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if(!Request.Url.ToString().ToLowerInvariant().Contains("default.aspx")) {
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

Also consider that this code will break non-ASP.NET requests when the application is running in Integrated Mode (in other it will redirect even requests for images and such).